# Need to access the xhr object when I call backbone fetch

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, jqxhr

I need to access the xhr object when I call Backbone fetch.

My understanding from the docs is that all Backbone.sync methods return a jqXHR object.

However, when I do this...

```
var xhr = this.collection.fetch();
console.log( xhr );
```

...xhr is coming up "undefined".  (The fetch call works as expected, and loads data from the server.)

Any ideas as to what I am missing?

**EDIT:**

My bad.  The collection fetch prototype was being overridden elsewhere and was not returning the jqXHR object.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you have overrided Backbone.sync or fetch methods. In this case you have to return the super call. For example:

```
fetch : function () {
  // ...
  return Backbone.Model.prototype.fetch.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe you can catch the XHR object in the success callback function that you would have to pass to the fetch() function.